# An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll,

Tags: c#

Additional Info: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

This is the code   -->

```
courseList.Add(new Course("Programming", "A190", new DateTime(2012, 09, 1), 
               new DateTime(2014, 06, 28), "The Programming course involves the units – Software Development using VC#, Databases, Information Theory and the Project Unit.", 
               "Abbey Park", 
               2, 
               unitList[0], 
               unitList[2], 
               unitList[3], 
               unitList[6]));
```

Comment: Indent 4 spaces if you want to post code. Welcome to this site btw.

Comment: What is unitList?  If it is an Array what is it's length, if it is a List what is it's count?

Comment: The `unitList` had fewer than seven elements (possibly it was an empty list).